# Conditional formatting: cell value equal to multiple numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using conditional formatting to format cells with color works fine if I want to do a single value, but now I'm in a situation where I'm looking at 40 different values that appear multiple times in a pretty big spreadsheet. Is there a way I could enter all the values into the field rather than repeating the operation 40 times? I would imagine that I could use a comma to do it but it didn't seem to work so maybe I made a mistake?

Comment: If you are Ok to put the 40 values in some cells then you can use OR formula e.g. =OR(A1=C1:C40) in your Conditional Format Formula Option.

Comment: Just to also mention in case you are not familiar, use $ prefix e.g. $C$1:$C$40 to keep the range fixed when coped to rest of the cells!

Answer (score 2):

Select the Range that you want to color (here I used column A), use Conditional Formatting, New Rules **Use a Formula to determine which Cells to Format**
Under **Format Values where this Formula is True** write:
**=OR(A1="value1",A1="value2",A1="value3",..,A1="value40")**
Choose the Format you want.
If the value is numeric don't use quotes ", just write the number.

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken but I don't think Excel allows you to use commas as a seperator in the OR function; you have to use semicolons. ";"

But I don't know if you can change that or not.

Comment: Comma is equivalent to semi colon in Formulas it is in **Excel Options Advanced Editing Options** and your computer settings you can change it